# Request full blocks using NBitcoin's NodesGroup

Tags: c#, blockchain, nbitcoin

I'm using https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin for a simple C# application, that just downloads the Bitcoin blockchain.

What I already achieved is downloading the block headers via `NodesGroup`:

```
var parameters = new NodeConnectionParameters();
parameters.TemplateBehaviors.Add(new ChainBehavior());
var group = new NodesGroup(Network.Main, parameters, new NodeRequirement()
{
    RequiredServices = NodeServices.Network
});
group.Connect();
//wait some time
var chain = parameters.TemplateBehaviors.Find<ChainBehavior>().Chain;
```

The only way of downloading the full blocks (with transactions) I found is using a single `Node`:

```
var node = new Node(/*whatever*/)
var blocks = node.GetBlocks(/*hash of the last block I want*/)
```

So here is my question: Is there a way of downloading the full blocks (with transactions) directly and in parallel from the connected nodes in `NodesGroup`, just like I did with the block headers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got informed, that NBitcoin currently does not support this feature. I will have to stick to the one node solution:

```
var node = new Node(/*whatever*/)
var blocks = node.GetBlocks(/*hash of the last block I want*/)
```